# What's the name of the package to record YouTube audio to mp3?

Tags: apt, package-management, purge

I'm trying to remove a package that records YouTube audio to .mp3 files but can't remember the package name.

I'm using `sudo apt-get purge <package name>` but I enter the package name incorrectly and then "Unable to locate package" is displayed.

Does anyone know the name of the the package?

Thanks

Comment: What package are you trying to find?

Comment: It's Youtube to MP3 package that I installed.

Comment: `youtube-to-mp3`?

Comment: In was indeed youtube-to-mp3. Thank you.

Comment: @Patrick Negus do we need to keep a close vote on this question as Jacob has verified AlexP's comment is correct and I've changed the title and body of question to reflect the comments??

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix We don't, I just got back and I'll remove it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list all installed packages](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages)

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following using the terminal:

1. To see all packages and look for the one you installed - `dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall`
2. To see a broader list - `dpkg -l`
3. Use `grep tool` to search for the two `keywords` you mentioned above - `dpkg --get-selections | grep [youtube-to-mp3]`

If using Ubuntu version greater than 14.04, use `apt list --installed`.

Then after identifying the package (note: options 1 & 2 will give you large outputs as I saw when I ran it) you can simple do:

For Ubuntu 14.04 and older:

```
sudo apt-get purge <the-package-name>
```

For Ubuntu 16.04 and newer:

```
sudo apt purge <the-package-name>
```

Comment: Instead of just copying and pasting from an existing answer please flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Patrick I am ignorant of that fact and did not do it with that intent. I believe pointing it out to a novice would have been the right thing than punishing me. So should I remove the answer and flag as you have pointed out.

Comment: @PatrickNegus I don't see where this is a copy/paste of an existing answer, sure, the commands are the same but it seems to be the OP's own answer. I agree the -1 might be a bit harsh. George, you can answer duplicates, if you like but they will get closed quickly and won't get many votes but there is no rule against answering them, in your own words.

Comment: @MarkKirby I'm sorry, a bit stressed out today and yes, I was a way too harsh. Sorry about that.

Comment: @George Make a quick edit to your answer and I'll upvote it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

`/var/log/apt/` contains log files describing which packages were installed, and when they were installed.

Answer (score 0):

To purge the package in question run:

```
sudo apt-get purge youtube-to-mp3
```

Comment: Actually it does: the question was what is the name of the package and I have provided it. See the comments below the question.

Comment: I edited your answer to show you what I meant. Plain command listings are rarely considered acceptable answers on and off StackExchange. Always include a minimal explanation for context.